# How to draw vertical lines on Highcharts graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts, I want to draw vertical lines on the values. Like;

[image]

How can I do that ? Thanks.

Here is my code

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'area'
        },
    title: {
        text: '<b> </b>'
    },
        xAxis: {

            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value / 1000 +'k';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) +'</b>';
            }
        },
            xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Mon',
            'Tue',
            'Wed',
            'Thu',
            'Fri',
            'Sat',
            'Sun'
        ],
        plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
            from: 5.5,
            to: 6.5,
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
        }]
    },

        plotOptions: {

            area: {
                pointStart: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Visit',
            data: [946, 733, 764, 887, 832,1423]
        }, {
            name: 'Unique',
            data: [746, 633, 664, 687,702,1266]
        }]
    });
});

});
    </script>
```

Comment: As an aside, you dont need the `$(function(){...` and `$(document).ready(function(){...` together, they're both one and the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will most likely have to use the [Highcharts renderer](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#Renderer) for this task, as what you want to do doesn't quite fit in with a grid, and doesn't quite fit in with plot lines.

I have made a [very simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/zYXar/), based on your code which shows drawing an arbitrary vertical line, in a hard-coded location. To achieve your goal you will have to calculate a few things, such as the x/y position for the start point of each line, and the height of the line based on that points value.

Here's a [slightly different example](http://jsfiddle.net/gXkhp/) with zIndex and a line as you actually want it, using the `V` path command to draw a vertical line.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be looking for Plot Bands and/or Plot Lines.

Here's some more information:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines

Answer (score 3):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/SxjAD/1/). From [Highcharts API](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--minorGridLineColor).

Answer (score 2):

If you want ony one line (and area starting from that):

```
xAxis:{     
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'red', // Color value
        //dashStyle: 'solid', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
        value: + new Date(), // Value of where the line will appear
        width: '2' // Width of the line    
    }],
    plotBands: [{
        color: '#FFFAFA', // Color value
        from:  +new Date(), // Start of the plot band
        to:    +new Date()+1000*24*3600*30, //30 days
    }],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include a new series with the type `column` and add the same data to this serie than the other serie that includes the point.

```
{
    /* Column type */
    type: 'column',
    name: '',
    data: [],
    color: '#ED1C24',
    pointWidth: 2,
    showInLegend: false,
    states: { hover: { enabled: false } }
}
```

Use this JSFiddle as guide: http://jsfiddle.net/NDpu6/